AWS Cognito Custom Auth Flow Returning “Incorrect username or password” for Passwordless Login
I’m implementing a custom passwordless authentication flow using AWS Cognito for my application. The idea is to allow users to log in with a phone number and an OTP sent via WhatsApp using Meta’s API.
I have implemented the following Lambda triggers for the custom authentication flow:

DefineAuthChallenge: Determines the next challenge and sets it as
CUSTOM_CHALLENGE.
CreateAuthChallenge: Generates the OTP, stores it temporarily, and sends it to the user via WhatsApp.
VerifyAuthChallengeResponse: Validates the OTP provided by the user.

The flow works as expected until the VerifyAuthChallengeResponse step. After verification, Cognito throws the following error:
NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password.

What I’ve Checked:

The VerifyAuthChallengeResponse Lambda successfully validates the OTP
and returns true for event.response.answerCorrect.
The phone number (username) is correctly formatted in E.164 format.
The Cognito user has the CONFIRMED status and required attributes (phone_number, phone_number_verified).
No typos in the event response properties.

What I Need Help With:

Why is Cognito throwing the “Incorrect username or password” error
even after the challenge is successfully verified?
Are there specific fields I need to set in the Lambda trigger
responses to ensure Cognito recognizes the authentication as
successful?
Is it possible that this issue arises because I’m testing with an
existing user who was created before implementing the custom
authentication flow?

Here’s an outline of my VerifyAuthChallengeResponse Lambda:
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const userAnswer = event.request.challengeAnswer;
    const correctAnswer = event.request.privateChallengeParameters.otp;

    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        event.response.answerCorrect = true;
    } else {
        event.response.answerCorrect = false;
    }

    return event;
};

the nestJs code:
async initiateAuth(phoneNumber: string): Promise<any> {
    const command = new InitiateAuthCommand({
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      AuthFlow: "CUSTOM_AUTH",
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: phoneNumber,
        password: "test@1234"
      },
    });

    try {
      const response = await this.client.send(command);
      return response;
    } catch (error: any) {
      this.logger.debug(
        `Error authenticating user, error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`,
      );
      throw error;
    }
  }

  async respondToAuthChallenge(
    username: string,
    phoneNumber: string,
    otp: string,
    session: string,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const command = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand({
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      ChallengeName: "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE",
      Session: session,
      ChallengeResponses: {
        USERNAME: username,
        ANSWER: otp,
      },
    });

    try {
      const response = await this.client.send(command);
      return response;
    } catch (error: any) {
      this.logger.debug(
        `Error responding to challenge: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`,
      );
      throw error;
    }
  }

Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be highly appreciated! Let me know if more details or logs are needed.

Problem:
I encountered an issue with AWS Cognito’s DefineAuthChallenge Lambda function. The function wasn’t handling the scenario where the authentication challenge (e.g., OTP validation) was successfully completed. This resulted in a NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password error.
Solution:
The problem was that the DefineAuthChallenge Lambda function didn’t correctly issue tokens when the challenge was successfully answered. To fix this, I added logic to handle the case where the challenge result was true.
Here is the updated code snippet:
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('Define Auth Challenge event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    if (event.triggerSource === "DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication") {
        // Check if this is the first challenge or the previous challenge was successfully answered
        if (event.request.session.length === 0 ||
            (event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeName === 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' &&
                event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].answer)) {
            console.log("Init authentication...");
            event.response.issueTokens = false; // Do not issue tokens yet
            event.response.failAuthentication = false; // Continue to the next challenge
            event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'; // Create a custom challenge
        } 
        // Handle the case where the challenge is successfully answered
        else if (event.request.session.length > 0 && event.request.session[0].challengeResult === true) {
            console.log("Authentication is done...");
            event.response.issueTokens = true; // Issue tokens
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
        } 
        // Handle failure case
        else {
            console.log("Failed to authenticate...");
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = true;
        }
    }

    return event;
};

Explanation:

The added block checks if the most recent session’s challengeResult is true.
If so, it sets event.response.issueTokens to true, allowing Cognito to issue tokens for the authenticated user.
Without this logic, Cognito will not issue tokens even if the challenge is answered correctly, resulting in the NotAuthorizedException.

Note: Ensure that the other Lambda triggers (CreateAuthChallenge and VerifyAuthChallengeResponse) are also implemented correctly to handle the OTP generation and validation process.
